# MySQL select formatted date from millisecond field

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I have a column in a MySQL database that contains a date as milliseconds (epoch). I want to build an SQL query that formats the date as something human readable (day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds in any format and time zone). Is there an SQL (or MySQL-specific) function to do this?

Comment: You could use `from_unixtime` function in a subquery. Check answer below.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try using the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function like this as given in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
 -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
```

You could also use formatting like this

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
    ->                      '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');
    -> '2007 30th November 10:30:59 2007'
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. My time was in milliseconds so a slight modification did exactly what I wanted: `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(\`column\` / 1000)`.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to get the microsecond from a field, use %f,

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(CREATETIME/1000,'%Y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s %f') from TABLE_NAME;

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(CREATETIME/1000,'%Y-%M-%d %H:%i:%s %f') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-March-18 16:02:54 342000                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Source : [MYSQL DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: If you're dividing milliseconds by 1000 to reduce to seconds, won't microseconds necessarily be 0?

Comment: It won't necessarily be 0, it'd be a multiple of 1000 (1000 ms per usec).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `ConvertTimeDelta`(duration int) RETURNS 
varchar(20) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE time_delta VARCHAR(20);
 DECLARE date_format VARCHAR(20);
 SET date_format = IF (duration > 3599999, '%H:%i:%s', '%i:%s');
 SET time_delta = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(duration/1000), date_format);
 RETURN time_delta;
END
```

For example
select ConvertTimeDelta(4800240)
result = 01:20:00
select ConvertTimeDelta(35076)
result = 00:35