# MySql Server 5.7 not saving milliseconds on DATETIME(3) column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I've got MySQL Server running on Armbian Bionic (Ubuntu 18.04.4), running on an Orange Pi Zero. MySQL server version is 5.7.29.

I've created a table, with a data type `DATETIME(3)`, that is, I'd like to store a date and a time with millisecond precision.

When I execute `INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES ('2020-02-04 12:34:46.789');` and then I execute `SELECT column1 FROM table1;` it shows:

**2020-02-04 12:34:47**

So it would appear like it's not saving the millisecond? But if I execute `SELECT NOW(3);` it shows:

**2020-02-04 20:25:33.077**

So it's handling milliseconds. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you select using MS? --  IE `SELECT MICROSECOND(column1) FROM table1 ;`  ??

Comment: Maybe this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176088/mysql-select-formatted-date-from-millisecond-field

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Zak. If I SELECT MICROSECOND(column1) it returns 0. So I guess it's not saving the milliseconds at all...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your column is using the default `DATETIME`. You can see the current table schema using the following query:

```
DESC table_name
```

Make sure you created the table with `DATETIME(3)`:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  column_name DATETIME(3)
)
```

You can make sure the output is using the precision. But you only get milliseconds in case the value is stored on a `DATETIME(3)` column:

```
SELECT CAST(column_name AS DATETIME(3)) FROM table_name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e7cd0361a0528ba9bdc6509eca481593)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, and sorry for the late reply. If I DESC table1, it is indeed DATETIME(3). If I SELECT CAST(column1 AS DATETIME(3)) FROM table1 I can see the milliseconds, but they are all zero. Also, if I SELECT MICROSECOND(column1) FROM table1 as per Zak's suggestion, it is also zero. So the milliseconds are definitely not being saved in the first place. It's not a display issue. The datetime is being rounded off to the nearest seconds when INSERTING into the table.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain this. Even though I created the column as **DATETIME(3)**, and even after executing `DESC table1` and getting the reply **DATETIME(3)**, out of sheer desperation, I tried using another database client other then MySql Workbench. I downloaded *DBeaver*, and edited the table. I saw that column1 was set to DATETIME (even though Workbench showed it as DATETIME(3)). So I made it DATETIME(3) and now it works! So it must be a bug in Workbench where, when creating or editing a DATETIME column, it's ignoring the fractional second specifier.